# Jquery append and add var

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, iframe, append

I use append method for add some html to div in the fly, but in this case I insert iframe with append into the div:

I need send var's value to this frame for works but I don't know if it's ok

**My code :**

```
var iframer="<?php echo "index.php?id=".$_REQUEST['select']."";?>";

jQuery("#popup_content").append("<div id=adm_popup><iframe src='iframer' width=100% marginwidth=0 height=800 marginheight=0 align=middle scrolling=auto frameborder=0></iframe></div>")
```

The problem it's how I can add the value of var `iframer` to `src` of iframe

Thank's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to concatenate with '+'

```
jQuery("#popup_content").append("<div id=adm_popup><iframe src='"+ iframer + "' width=100% marginwidth=0 height=800 marginheight=0 align=middle scrolling=auto frameborder=0></iframe></div>")
```